# Find all combinations of features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I need to transform my binary coded feature matrix into a matrix that consists of all possible combinations of feature interactions. By all I mean literally all combinations (every set of 2, every set of 3, every set of 4, every set of all, etc).

Anyone know if there is a way to do this with sklearn.preprocessing ? Or other libraries?

Input this array into some function or method:

```
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

And get this as Output

```
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Each row in the new matrix represents [x1*x2, x1*x3, x2*x3, x1*x2*x3]

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] showing exactly what you are after.

Comment: Can you explain why this output? Seems unclear to me

Comment: Same to me, too.

Comment: Sorry the matrix was incorrect. I corrected the output matrix. It's an exhaustive combination of every feature with combination lengths from 2 to count of features. Every feature must be multiplied by every other feature in all possible lengths. So feature 1 with feature 2, and feature 1 with feature 3, and feature 2 with 3, and all 3 features multiplied together.

Comment: Of course in my actual application I have many, many more features. This type of full feature interaction has domain specific applications in my field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is know as the [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). So you want to find the powerset of your features and then multiply the corresponding binary values, which is basically taking a [`np.bitwise_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html). So here's how you could do this:

- Obtain the powerset finding all combinations of the features up to length `len(features)`
- Reduce with `np.logical_and.reduce`
- Append to a list containing all `sets` in the powerset

---

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 1]])

from itertools import chain, combinations

features = a.T.tolist()
power_set = []
for comb in chain.from_iterable(combinations(features, r) 
                               for r in range(2,len(features)+1)):
    power_set.append(np.logical_and.reduce(comb).view('i1').tolist())
```

Which will give you:

```
np.array(power_set).T

array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Great thank you. This is an elegant solution. But do you think this is a feasible way to create the power set when my initial matrix will already be something like 1,000,000 rows by 5,000 features (something in that range)?

Comment: No not really. There is no vectorized way of creating a power-set, that I know of. So this is computationally expensive. Perhaps limit the range of combinations. Or look at some other feature eng tools if that's what you're after such as `featuretools` @MichaelHavlin

Answer (score 0):

Update: Ok, one for loop gone, one to go.

There is a nice function for the powerset in the [recipes section of itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

This should work. It's not yet optimized for speed.
The nested for loops can probably be be removed if this provides the result you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations, chain

features = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0],
                     [1, 1, 1]])

n = features.shape[1]

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

# get all combinations, we will use this as indices for the columns later
indices = list(powerset(range(n)))

# remove the empty subset
indices.pop(0)

print(indices)

data = []

for i in indices:

    print()
    print(i)
    _ = features[:, i]
    print(_)

    x = np.prod(_, axis=1)
    print(x)
    data.append(x)

print(np.column_stack(data))
```